# Safari cutting off bottom background in popup with scrolling div

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, safari, background, popup

The image below illustrates a popup overlay containing 3 sections. Top, scrolling content and bottom.

Issue: **Safari somehow cuts off the bottom too soon**.

[This Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-safari-popup-missing-bottom-background) also replicates it.

So far I have figured out, that it may have something to do with the size of the scrolling area. If I remove a portion of the text, the issue disappear.

Unfortunately I don't have access to a Mac at the moment, and therefore not able to 'inspect' the browser in developer tools. So I hope someone can shed some light on this...

[image: Chrome vs Safari regarding popup overlay]

Comment: Can you give source code?

Comment: There is a link to a stackblitz in the post

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get access to a Mac, and the issue turned out to be quite trivial and must have something to do with Safaris interpretation of flex.

I had to wrap the button "row" parent box in another div:

**Before:**

```
<ngx-smart-modal #termsModal1 [identifier]="'termsModal1'" customClass="nsm-centered">
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="nsm-body content-wrapper mt-5">
      <div class="overflow-container">
        <div class="pl-3 pr-3">
          <h3>Terms and conditions</h3>
          <ed-terms></ed-terms>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <!-- RELEVANT PART -->
      <div class="row m-0 pb-4 pl-3 pr-3 clearfix">
        <div class="btn btn-primary btn-block col-12 mt-3" (click)="termsModal1.close()">I ACCEPT THE TERMS</div>
        <div class="btn btn-info btn-block col-12" (click)="termsModal1.close()" i18n>CLOSE</div>
      </div>
    <!-- /RELEVANT PART -->
    </div>
  </div>
</ngx-smart-modal>
```

**After:**

I've also removed all the 'clearfix' stuff that I had added in frustration ;-)

```
<ngx-smart-modal #termsModal2 [identifier]="'termsModal2'" customClass="nsm-centered">
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="nsm-body content-wrapper mt-5">
      <div class="overflow-container">
        <div class="pl-3 pr-3">
          <h3>Terms and conditions</h3>
          <ed-terms></ed-terms>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- RELEVANT PART -->
      <div>
        <div class="row m-0 pb-4 pl-3 pr-3">
          <div class="btn btn-primary btn-block col-12 mt-3" (click)="termsModal2.close()">I ACCEPT THE TERMS</div>
          <div class="btn btn-info btn-block col-12" (click)="termsModal2.close()" i18n>CLOSE</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /RELEVANT PART -->
    </div>
  </div>
</ngx-smart-modal>
```

[The stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-safari-popup-missing-bottom-background) has been updated accordingly to reflect both cases.